# Super Paper Mario freezes in world 2-2

Tags: technical-issues, nintendo-wii, super-paper-mario

Whenever I talk to Mimi in world 2-2 of Super Paper Mario my Wii freezes. Do I have a bad disk, or is it my Wii? (Actually, I can talk to her once, but if I try again, the freeze happens.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_Paper_Mario):

> "PAL copies of the game contain a bug if the language is set to English, German, or Spanish. In Chapter 2-2, the game will freeze if Mario speaks to the character Mimi without first picking up the key. Nintendo of Europe is replacing the game disc for no charge with a version that does not contain the bug."